# secure communication without adding cert on requests in python

Tags: python, https, certificate

i have requested the resource which was communicating on https. but there were no certs added in request calls. But the response was secured data. I want to know why the response was a secure data even when there were no certs on request calls. i was using python 2.7.9 and server was in java bootstrap

Comment: Please provide your code, http request and response

Comment: Did you cancel SSL certificate verification?